# How do I can show ogre 3d letters?

Tags: c++, c++11, game-engine, ogre

I'm trying to show letters ogre but only get a black screen and I followed a tutorial: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Simple+Text+Output
I have not yet clear because I can not see the letters on the screen, I do not get compile errors. This is the code that I have:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Root* root = new Ogre::Root("config/plugins.cfg", "config/ogre.cfg", "config/ogre.log");
  check_config(root);
  RenderWindow* window = root->initialise(true, "Titulo"); // crea la ventana
  SceneManager* scene_manager = root->createSceneManager(ST_GENERIC, "SceneManager"); //crea el scene
  load_resources("config/resources.cfg");
  Camera* camera = root->getSceneManager("SceneManager")->createCamera("Camera"); //inicializo la camara
  Viewport* viewport = root->getAutoCreatedWindow()->addViewport(camera); //inicializo camara
  // get the resource manager
 ResourceGroupManager &resGroupMgr = ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton();
 // tell it to look at this location
 resGroupMgr.addResourceLocation("media", "media");
 // get the font manager
 FontManager &fontMgr = FontManager::getSingleton();
 // create a font resource
 ResourcePtr font = fontMgr.create("MyFont","General");
 // set as truetype
 font->setParameter("type","truetype");
 // set the .ttf file name
 font->setParameter("source","MyFont.fontdef");
 // set the size
 font->setParameter("size","26");
 // set the dpi
 font->setParameter("resolution","96");
 // load the ttf
 font->load();
  //create_light(root);
  OverlayManager& overlayMgr = OverlayManager::getSingleton();
  Ogre::OverlayContainer* panel = static_cast<OverlayContainer*>(
  overlayMgr.createOverlayElement("Panel", "PanelName"));
  panel->setMetricsMode(Ogre::GMM_PIXELS);
  panel->setPosition(10, 10);
  panel->setDimensions(300, 120);
  TextAreaOverlayElement* textArea = static_cast<TextAreaOverlayElement*>(
  overlayMgr.createOverlayElement("TextArea", "TextAreaName"));
  textArea->setMetricsMode(Ogre::GMM_PIXELS);
  textArea->setPosition(0, 0);
  textArea->setDimensions(300, 120);
  textArea->setCharHeight(26);
 // set the font name to the font resource that you just created.
  textArea->setFontName("MyFont");
 // say something
  textArea->setCaption("Hello, World!");
  Ogre::Overlay* overlay = overlayMgr.create("OverlayName");
  overlay->add2D(panel);
  panel->addChild(textArea);
  overlay->show();
   root->startRendering();
  delete window;
  delete scene_manager;
  delete root;
  return 0;
}
```

I should clarify that I have a media folder where saved a file named: MyFont.fontdef is a configuration file with font

```
MyFont
{
    type         truetype
    source         arial.ttf
    size         16
    resolution     72
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your camera isn't configured properly. Try:

```
camera->setPosition(Ogre::Vector3(0,30,30));
camera->lookAt(Ogre::Vector3(0,0,0));
```